# What is consider a bad URL

Tags: swift, url

Shouldn't this code print out failed

```
func dummyFetch()  {
    let urlString = "as-2k2i2i asdfadsf;kkaqfkqj; q;klef ;k;lqke"
    guard let _ = URL(string: urlString) else {
        print("failed")
        return
    }
    print("passed")
}
```

Cause right now it is printing out passed for me. Im a little confused, what will need to be passed in the urlString to print out failed?

Comment: If you create `URLComponents` from that string you will see that the whole thing is treated as the `path` portion of a URL. No scheme, no host, just a path. All of the spaces are encoded to `%20`.

Comment: `URL(string:)` (as of iOS 17/macOS 14) uses [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) to parse a URL. Read through that specification to see what would be considered invalid. Also consider using `URL(string:encodingInvalidCharacters:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what will need to be passed in the urlString to print out failed

Here's an example of a string that will result in a `nil` URL:

```
let url = URL(string: "h t t p://what")
```

Here's a less drastic example:

```
let url = URL(string: "")
```

It's positively useful to have strings of this sort on hand, because sometimes you need to unit test something that should fail coherently on being given a bad URL string.